# How to push multiple items in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of objects. What I try to do is to push all items to a specific location inside database, because with push call each item will be assigned an unique id.

I try to place Firebase push inside a loop but I think it's somehow not right to do so.
(web app here)

```
const array = [{title: 'one'},{title:'two'}, {title: 'three'}]

array.map(item => {
          FirebaseRef.child(`boards/${boardId}/containers`).push(item)
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following, using the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method, will work:

```
const array = [{ title: 'one' }, { title: 'two' }, { title: 'three' }]

var updates = {};
array.map(item => {
     var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child(`boards/${boardId}/containers/`).push().key;
     updates[`boards/${boardId}/containers/` + newPostKey] = item;
});
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```